Where does the radar technology stand?
This month at the IDEAS 2024 defense exhibition, Pakistani state-owned company NRTC and a private company, BlueSurge, have unveiled their new surveillance radar, AM-350S.
The following are some features of the radar:

NRTC AM-350S Long-Range 3D Air Surveillance Radar


the AM-350S is a Gallium-Nitride (GaN)-based active electronically scanned array (AESA) radar with digital beamforming capabilities.


NRTC and Blue Surge state that the AM-350S provides a surveillance range of 350 km. It has a 360° field-of-view and flexible elevation features, enabling it to monitor altitudes of up to 60,000 feet.


The AM-350S also provides resilient anti-jamming capabilities with frequency hopping, vector control, and side-lobe suppression. Being an AESA-based system, the AM-350S can leverage its multiple TRMs to emit in different or unique frequencies in one pulse, making it more difficult for an enemy ECM system to single out a particular frequency for jamming.


AM-350S Specifications
Radar Specifications
Frequency Band: S-Band
Maximum Range: 350 km
Range for Fighter-Sized Targets (2m2 RCS): 200 km
Range for Drone-Sized Targets (0.1m2 RCS): 80 km
Azimuth Coverage: 360°
Elevation Coverage: -6° to +20° Height
Coverage: <60,000 feet Rotation
Speed: 6 RPM (10-second refresh rate)
Antenna Count: 64 TRM Peak
Power: >400 watts
IFF Specifications
Range: Up to 450 km Frequency
Bands: 1030 MHz (interrogation) and 1090 MHz (response)
Modes of Operation: Modes 1, 2, 3/A, C, S, ADS-B
Compliance: ICAO-compliant

I am a layman in this area.
Is this a big, moderate, or mediocre achievement on their part? Where does their technology stand in the world arena? Can you give me an analogy so that I can comprehend?

At least at first glance, I don't see anything that looks like it's advancing the state of the art--but assuming it lives up to what they're claiming, it's close enough to state of the art to be a pretty serious achievement anyway.

@JerryCoffin, I don't see anything that looks like it's advancing the state of the art --- why is that?

@user366312 likely checking the capabilities of other systems - worth some effort in your research...

Here's an article outlining some of the history and approximate (publicly known) state of the art as of 2012: https://www.microwavejournal.com/articles/17992-evolution-of-aesa-radar-technology At least based on the specs, it's not clear this exceeds what that describes.
